# boost::lockfree::queue is eating up my CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

So I wrote a multi-thread program using boost::lockfree::queue, and the code is pretty much the same as the given example 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html. Well, I have 4 queues and the data is a struct rather than int.

The problem is that my program eats up 95% of my cpu when running and it's super slow. After a little investigation I found out that boost::lockfree::queue::pop takes 80% of the cpu usage, which isn't surprising because of these two loops

```
while (!done) {
    while (queue.pop(value))
        ++consumer_count;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to reduce the cpu usage, or should I upgrade my CPUs? I am using boost 1.61, visual studio 2015 on windows 10, btw.

Thanks so much

Comment: I think you missed the whole point of the lockfree queue. You probably want a blocking queue! The point of lockfree/waitfree queues is that there is no explicit blocking synchronization required to read and write concurrently to the queue. This way you can avoid the overhead of lock contention and have rather predictable read/write timing behaviour.
Your threads are indeed supposed to work the whole time and never block. If thats not what you want, i.e. you want to wait until something is available in the queue, then use a blocking queue implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expected? The following piece of code is the same as yours (in terms of eating CPU)

```
int counter = 0;
bool condition_1 = false;
bool condition_2 = false;
while(!condition_1) {
  while(!condition_2) {
    ++counter;
    condition_2 = true;
  }
}
```

What you need, IMHO, is some notification mechanism (e.g. condition_variable), when poll queue. Otherwise, constantly polling it, obviously, eats cpu.